# Eclipse, missing requirements during Eclipse package installation

Tags: python, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I'm trying to install PyDev on my Ubuntu 12.4.04 [following these instructions](http://codingtip.blogspot.it/2012/04/how-to-install-eclipse-and-pydev-for.html).
When I select the PyDev packages among the Eclipse package list, Eclipse tells me:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
>   not be found.   Software being installed: Pydev Mylyn Integration
>   0.4.0 (org.python.pydev.mylyn.feature.feature.group 0.4.0)   Missing requirement: Pydev Mylyn Integration 0.4.0
>   (org.python.pydev.mylyn.feature.feature.group 0.4.0) requires
>   'org.eclipse.mylyn.context.core 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Do you know how to solve this?

**EDIT:** I selected the "Use all the available download websites" option and it started the download. But it got new errors:

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=PlatformProfile,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). Problems downloading artifact:
>   osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev,3.5.0.201405201709. Error reading signed
>   content:/tmp/signatureFile8427466212879929206.jar An error occurred
>   while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile8427466212879929206.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.analysis,3.5.0.201405201709.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6225334791154145595.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile6225334791154145595.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact:
>   osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.codecompletion,3.5.0.201405201709. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile1625250666117296864.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile1625250666117296864.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.debug,3.5.0.201405201709. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5513082187501911158.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile5513082187501911158.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.fastparser,3.5.0.201405201709.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile605486589496460440.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile605486589496460440.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,com.python.pydev.refactoring,3.5.0.201405201709.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile144672797460509165.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile144672797460509165.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev,3.5.0.201405201709. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6260050602791980202.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile6260050602791980202.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.ast,3.5.0.201405201709. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile7925013072583879479.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile7925013072583879479.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.core,3.5.0.201405201709. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6502114115388448316.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile6502114115388448316.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact:
>   osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.customizations,3.5.0.201405201709. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile646114539488211012.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile646114539488211012.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.debug,3.5.0.201405201709. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5554172731601599412.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile5554172731601599412.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.django,3.5.0.201405201709.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2081112544030499068.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile2081112544030499068.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.python.pydev.feature,3.5.0.201405201709.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile8761783145012931325.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile8761783145012931325.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.help,3.5.0.201405201709. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile4140872971434327198.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile4140872971434327198.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.jython,3.5.0.201405201709.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile1472620833557689910.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile1472620833557689910.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.mylyn,0.4.0. Error reading
>   signed content:/tmp/signatureFile6287310346304363477.jar An error
>   occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile6287310346304363477.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,org.python.pydev.mylyn.feature,0.4.0. Error
>   reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2932536020816821753.jar An
>   error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile2932536020816821753.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.parser,3.5.0.201405201709.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile2860560593863228850.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile2860560593863228850.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.refactoring,3.5.0.201405201709.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile5444565411686316987.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile5444565411686316987.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_core,3.5.0.201405201709.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile644095121866711816.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile644095121866711816.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact:
>   osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_interactive_console,3.5.0.201405201709.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile708235382114637181.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile708235382114637181.jar Problems downloading
>   artifact: osgi.bundle,org.python.pydev.shared_ui,3.5.0.201405201709.
>   Error reading signed content:/tmp/signatureFile8183417620218922292.jar
>   An error occurred while processing the signatures for the file:
>   /tmp/signatureFile8183417620218922292.jar

Comment: Have you selected `Contact all updates sites...` checkbox?

Comment: Thanks, it starts the installation but it gets a new error. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It occurs because you are using probably older version of eclipse like Helios , I got the same problem. But when I switched to the KEPLER version the error vanished. I hope it helps!!